# topology of normed linear space

Tags: functional-analysis

I need a detailed solution of the following problems:

**(1).** Let ܸ$V=C^1 \left[0,1\right]$,  $X=\left(C[0,1],\left\lVert  .    \right\rVert \right)$ where the norm on $X$ is the sup norm,

$Y=(C[0,1],\left\lVert  .  \right\rVert_2)$: The space with  $\left\lVert\ f \right\rVert_2$=$\sqrt{\int_0^1 \lvert\ f(x) \rvert^2dx}^2$

Then ܸ$V$ is

(A) dense in $X$ but NOT in $Y$,

(B) dense in $Y$ but NOT in $X$,

(C) dense in both $X$ and $Y$,

(D) neither dense in $X$ nor dense in $Y$,

Comment: May you include what you have tried? Do you know Weierstrass approximation theorem?

Comment: Something in the definition of $H$ seems to be missing.

Comment: no....h is defined exactly as above

Comment: @AS you're missing either "$<\infty$" or "converges" in the definition. Also, please [format your questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/81360).

Comment: Since you're asking about two distinct problems, you should make two distinct question posts.  Also, you should always include your thoughts/attempts on the question, especially if you're asking for detailed solutions.

Comment: @ Omnomnomnom:oh sorry,the sequence in the problem converges to 1.i have edited the question

Comment: the question 1 is not clear to me.

Comment: ohh ok. So for the 1st question check what happens with polynomial space.

Comment: Please, post only one question in one post. Posting several questions in the same post is discouraged and such questions may be put on hold, see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6464/posting-multiple-questions-as-one?). In this particular case, I think you could remove the second part from your question, since you have asked about it [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1607886/showing-that-a-subset-of-l2-is-closed).

Answer (score 2):

For first question,

Set of polynomials is dense in C[0,1] with sup norm and any polynomial function is continuously differentiable. so set of all polynomials say $P$ is contained in $C^1[0,1]$ and hence $\bar P\subset cl(C^1[0,1])$ i.e. $C[0,1]\subset C^1[0,1]$
hence it is dense in X.

on similar lines try for Y