# Showing that sequences such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {x_n\over n} =1$ form a closed subset of $l^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $H= \left\{(x_n)\in\ell^2 : \sum_{n=1}^\infty {x_n\over n} =1\right\}$

I need to show that H is closed in $l^2$.

then, it is sufficient to show that, closure of H $\subseteq$ H.

let x=($x_i$)$\in$closure of H,$\exists$ a sequence ($x^{(n)}$) with $x^{(n)}$=($x^{(n)}_1$,$x^{(n)}_2$,$x^{(n)}_3$,......)such that $\left\lVert x^{(n)}-x\right\rVert_2$ $\to$0 as n$\to$$\infty$

now, after this step, I am not able to complete the solution. please give a detailed solution.

thanks a lot...

Comment: Why are you considering the closure in $\ell^2$ with respect to the sup norm and not w.r.t. its natural norm $\|x\|_2 = \left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty |x_i|^2\right)^{1/2}$?

Comment: @Roland seems to be corrected now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $x=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n,...)\in \bar {H}$. T.P. $x\in H$. 
as $x\in \bar H$ there exists seq say $x^n=(x^n_1,x^n_2,x^n_3,....)\in H$ converging to $x$. $\implies$ $\|x^n-x\|_2< \varepsilon$ $\implies$ on simplifying we will get $|x_k^n-x_k|< \varepsilon$ $\forall n \geq n_0$, $\forall k$. So $(x^n_k)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\to x_k$ for each k.
Now $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x^n_k/k=1 $ for each $n$. taking limit as n tends to infinity,  $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x_k/k=1 $

Comment: :could you answer the following problem on denseness or even give a hint:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1599384/topology-of-normed-linear-space

Answer (score 3):

I was asked to look at this.  Looking at it, I think it's possible to simplify Urgje's answer.  Give $\bf{f}$ the same meaning as in Urgje's answer, i.e., $(1,1/2,1/3,\ldots,1/n,\ldots)$.  We have ${\bf f}\in l^2$ because $||{\bf f}||^2 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/n^2$ by definition of the norm and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/n^2$ is a well-known convergent series, so $||{\bf f}||^2<\infty$.

Now, consider the function $g: {\bf x}\to ({\bf x},{\bf f})$ for ${\bf x}\in l^2$. The function $g$ takes $l^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, according to what the scalar field for $l^2$ is.  The function $g$  is continuous in ${\bf x}$ because $|({\bf x},{\bf f})|\le ||{\bf x}||\,||{\bf f}||$ (Rudin *Functional Analysis* 12.2) and so $|g({\bf x}_1)-g({\bf x}_2)|=|({\bf x}_1-{\bf x}_2,{\bf f})|\le ||{\bf x}_1-{\bf x}_2||\,||{\bf f}||\to 0$ when ${{\bf x}_1\to {\bf x}_2}$.  Thus, the inverse image of a closed set under $g$ is closed (Baby Rudin 4.8).

For any ${\bf x}\in l^2$ we have ${\bf x} \in H$ iff $1=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n/n = ({\bf x},{\bf f})$.  Thus, $H$ is the inverse image of $\{1\}$ under $g$, and we are done.

Comment: nice. this looks much simpler

Answer (score 2):

Note that
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{f}=(1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\cdots )
\end{equation*}
is contained in $l^{2}$. Let
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{x}=(x_{1},x_{2},\cdots )\in l^{2}
\end{equation*}
Then for $\mathbf{x}\in H$
\begin{equation*}
(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{f})=1
\end{equation*}
I think it is useful to switch to
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{x}-\frac{(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{f})}{\parallel \mathbf{f}%
\parallel ^{2}}\mathbf{f}
\end{equation*}
(which becomes
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{x}-\frac{1}{\parallel \mathbf{f}\parallel ^{2}}\mathbf{f}
\end{equation*}
for $\mathbf{x}\in H$.) Now
\begin{equation*}
(\mathbf{y},\mathbf{f})=0
\end{equation*}
which defines a closed subspace $K$ of $l^{2}$. \ Now suppose that $\{
\mathbf{x}^{j}\}\subset H$ is Cauchy, so it has a limit $\mathbf{x}\in l^{2}$
and so does $\{\mathbf{y}^{j}\}$ in $K$. But then it follows that
\begin{equation*}
(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{f})=\lim_{j\rightarrow \infty }(\mathbf{x}^{j},\mathbf{f}
)=1
\end{equation*}