# Checking closedness of subset of normed space

Tags: functional-analysis

Show that the following subsets are closed in $C[0,1]$:

1. $S=\{f\in C[0,1] : f(x) \le 0 \,\,\forall x\in[0,1]\}$
2. $S=\{f\in C[0,1] : f(0)=0 \}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can even use sequential criteria. For any point of cl(S) say f, there is a seqn $(f_n)$ of elements of S converging to.f. so use the condition n you can prove that f is in S. Hence S will be closed in both cases

Suppose $f\in \bar{S}$ then by definition there exists a sequence of members of S say $f_n$ which converges to $f$. (now observe that convergence in sup norm is same as uniform convergence of sequence of functions.) As $f_n\in S$, $f_n(x)\leq 0$ for all $x\in [0,1]$ and for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, so $f_n \leq 0$ for all $n$, now as $f_n$ converges to $f$using the definition of convergence we can show that $f\leq 0$. Try it otherwise i will give further explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $S=\{f\in C[0,1] : f(x) \le 0 \,\,\forall x\in[0,1]\}$.  This is closed iff for every sequence $f_n\to f$, if all $f_n\in S$ then $f\in S$.  (Baby Rudin 2.18(d).)

Now, convergence in $C[0,1]$ is with respect to the supremum or $L^\infty$ norm, $||g||=\sup_{x\in [0,1]} |g(x)|$.  (Baby Rudin 7.14.)  Thus if $f_n\to f$ then $\sup_{x\in [0,1]} |f_n(x)-f(x)|\to 0$, and thus we have $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)$ for each $x\in [0,1]$.

If $f_n\in S$ for all $n$, we have $f_n(x)\le 0$ for all $n$ and $x$ by the definition of $S$.  In $\mathbb{R}$, we have that $(-\infty, 0]$ is a closed set.  Thus, if $f_n(x)\le 0$ for all $n$ we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)\le 0$.  Because $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)$, this proves that $f(x)\le 0$ for all $x$, and so $f\in S$ as desired.

(This is an elaboration on Prajakta's answer which I have posted because the original poster requested clarification and such clarification is too long to fit in a comment.)

Comment: yess. nice clarification. thanks.

Comment: @ForgotALot:could you give a solution for the following post using the same approach : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1607886/showing-that-a-subset-of-l2-is-closed

Comment: @AbhishekShrivastava for that post this approach might be a little complicated in terms of notations.

Comment: I have added an answer to the other post as requested, based on Urgje's answer there.  I didn't see that use of the sequence definition of closed set led to simplification there, although I did rely on Baby Rudin again.

Comment: i have tried to give an argument based on sequential criteria for that post. @AbhishekShrivastava and ForgotAlot pls verify it and do comment if there is any ambiguity. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hint. Take $f\in C[0,1]\setminus S$. Since $f(x)>0$ somewhere, and $f$ is continuous, there exists an $\delta$ such that $f(y)>0$ for all $|x-y|<\delta$. Then...

Comment: I think $f\in C[0,1]\setminus S$ only implies $f>0$ somewhere, not everywhere.  However, since $f$ is continuous that somewhere has to include an open interval where $f(x)>\epsilon$, so I think the rest of your idea may go through.

Comment: Oops you are right!